# How do I make sure null and empty string fields arent added to my documents in firestore Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am  adding objects to a document and I want to make sure empty strings and  null instances don't add fields as I only want to create fields once they have been actually added

```
 await updateDoc(itemRef,
 {thing: '3232',
    thing2: null,
    thing3:'' });
    }
```

how do I make sure only thing: 3232 is in the new document  and the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to just write a function that filters the property keys based on value:

```js
function filterInPlace(obj) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
        if (obj[key] == null || obj[key] == '')
            delete obj[key]
}
```

Comment: Thank I will use that I didnt want to edit the object but I will just make a copy of it first Thank you